# App permission settings retained in Android with React Native

Tags: android, react-native, runtime-permissions

I ran into a bit of trouble with a project I'm working on. I'm building out the permission logic (prompting the user in runtime) do display the user on the map, but as a response I always get `never_ask_again`. If I check the apps permission settings then location is enabled there. This makes it hard to build out and test some of the logic. I've tried uninstalling the app and cleaning the project, nothing seems to help.

Is there a way how I could reset the permission settings for this app on my phone or what's the solution to this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this, this command seems to give me the desired result - `adb shell pm clear com.appName`